# zxing library (in scala) not decoding images taken with cell phone's camera

Tags: scala, zxing, pdf417

I'm trying to decode **pdf417** type barcodes. For this I'm using "**zxing**" library in scala.

Code:

```
def decodePDF417FromImage(imageFile: File): Unit = {
    try {
      val image = ImageIO.read(imageFile)
      val source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(image)
      val bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source))

      val hints = new java.util.HashMap[DecodeHintType, Any]()
      hints.put(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER, true)

      val reader = new MultiFormatReader()
      val result: Result = reader.decode(bitmap, hints)

      if (result != null) {
        val decoded = result.getText
        println(decoded)
            }
      else {
        println("No PDF417 Barcode Found!")
      }
    } catch {
      case ex: NotFoundException =>
        println("No PDF417 Barcode Found!")
      case ex: java.lang.NullPointerException =>
        ex.printStackTrace()
      case ex: Exception =>
        ex.printStackTrace()
    }
  }

  val imageFile = new File("path-to-image")
  decodePDF417FromImage(new File(ouputFile))
```

Above code is working fine if I take **screenshot of image from google** - but if I take image with my **cell phone's camera** (opening image in laptop browser/media and capturing image from cell phone) and run above code it always give "**No Barcode Found**".

I've checked with some online tools, both screenshot image's barcode and cell phone image's barcode are decoding fine. (https://online-barcode-reader.inliteresearch.com/)

Another scenario is, if I capture image from cell phone's camera (which does not work) and open it in laptop's Image Viewer - then take screenshot and run that image. In this case it worked.

I've tried to convert type of image from **jpg** (cell phone's image) to **png** (screenshot of laptop) but it does not work as well. Also I tried to enhance image taken from cell phone's camera and then apply **zxing** but it does not work.

First I think I'm capturing image from laptop's screen that's why it is not working, but on the other hand online tools are giving decoded texts. So I got confused - guide me how to solve above.

Image I've used (https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fbarcodelive.org%2Fdrivers-license-barcode&psig=AOvVaw2QfoD8_3srZb-D2Q8ZoVpL&ust=1700036039153000&source=images&cd=vfe&opi=89978449&ved=0CBIQjRxqFwoTCPiV4vOFw4IDFQAAAAAdAAAAABAL) - First Image in it with pdf417 barcode.